# WSO2 Cloud Gateway How to add new proxy service

Tags: wso2

I need to add a new proxy service in Cloud Gateway but I cannot find any "service-add" option at the left menu. I would like to use CG without agents, how can I do that ?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WSO2-CG it is not possible to add directly a new entry, it has to be executed from others products from WSO2 stack where the CG agent is installed, therefore WSO2-CG only works with products within WSO2 stack